# Instance of closure checking

Tags: php, anonymous-function

We have an anonymous function in a stdclass object like following code:

```
$std = new \stdclass();
$std->method = function(){echo "Hi I'm  instance of Closure.";};

echo get_class($std->method); // prints "Closure"

if ($std->method instanceof Closure) {
    echo "Happy Ending."; // This line never gets executed.
}
```

anonymous function are instance of Closure class, but when I check it with `instanceof` keyword it doesn't return true. what's the problem?

Comment: Maybe you have to check whether the function is `insatnceof \Closure`? I mean namespace.

Comment: Works fine [here](https://eval.in/189853), seems to be a problem of namespace [indeed](https://eval.in/189856).

Comment: @aijalon thank you, it'w working with \Cloure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in namespace I had to use `\Closure` instead of `Closure`.